# Why is my app is crashing with IllegalArgumentException?

Tags: android, crash

I have a service which starts after installation of the app, when the service starts it crashes the app. It is possible that the database file is not yet created? I do not know what to do there.

Error:

```
07-31 11:41:56.333: E/DatabaseUtils(21572): Writing exception to parcel
07-31 11:41:56.333: E/DatabaseUtils(21572): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 2 is null
07-31 11:41:56.333: E/DatabaseUtils(21572):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:164)
07-31 11:41:56.333: E/DatabaseUtils(21572):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindAllArgsAsStrings(SQLiteProgram.java:200)
07-31 11:41:56.333: E/DatabaseUtils(21572):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
07-31 11:41:56.333: E/DatabaseUtils(21572):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
07-31 11:41:56.333: E/DatabaseUtils(21572):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:400)
07-31 11:41:56.333: E/DatabaseUtils(21572):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:294)
07-31 11:41:56.333: E/DatabaseUtils(21572):     at com.piqsho.p.d.h.CP.query(CP.java:542)
07-31 11:41:56.333: E/DatabaseUtils(21572):     at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:652)
07-31 11:41:56.333: E/DatabaseUtils(21572):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:189)
07-31 11:41:56.333: E/DatabaseUtils(21572):     at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:113)
07-31 11:41:56.333: E/DatabaseUtils(21572):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:351)
07-31 11:41:56.333: E/DatabaseUtils(21572):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
07-31 11:41:56.417: E/AndroidRuntime(21586): FATAL EXCEPTION: ServiceStartArguments
07-31 11:41:56.417: E/AndroidRuntime(21586): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 2 is null
07-31 11:41:56.417: E/AndroidRuntime(21586):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:167)
07-31 11:41:56.417: E/AndroidRuntime(21586):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
07-31 11:41:56.417: E/AndroidRuntime(21586):    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:366)
07-31 11:41:56.417: E/AndroidRuntime(21586):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:373)
07-31 11:41:56.417: E/AndroidRuntime(21586):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:316)
07-31 11:41:56.417: E/AndroidRuntime(21586):    at com.piqsho.p.s.SIMS.getNewChatMessages(SIMS.java:186)
07-31 11:41:56.417: E/AndroidRuntime(21586):    at com.piqsho.p.s.SIMS$ServiceHandler$1.run(SIMS.java:81)
07-31 11:41:56.417: E/AndroidRuntime(21586):    at com.piqsho.p.s.SIMS$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(SIMS.java:73)
07-31 11:41:56.417: E/AndroidRuntime(21586):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
07-31 11:41:56.417: E/AndroidRuntime(21586):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
07-31 11:41:56.417: E/AndroidRuntime(21586):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
07-31 11:41:57.428: E/DatabaseUtils(21572): Writing exception to parcel
07-31 11:41:57.428: E/DatabaseUtils(21572): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null
07-31 11:41:57.428: E/DatabaseUtils(21572):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:164)
07-31 11:41:57.428: E/DatabaseUtils(21572):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindAllArgsAsStrings(SQLiteProgram.java:200)
07-31 11:41:57.428: E/DatabaseUtils(21572):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
07-31 11:41:57.428: E/DatabaseUtils(21572):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
07-31 11:41:57.428: E/DatabaseUtils(21572):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:400)
07-31 11:41:57.428: E/DatabaseUtils(21572):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:294)
07-31 11:41:57.428: E/DatabaseUtils(21572):     at com.piqsho.p.d.h.CP.query(CP.java:542)
07-31 11:41:57.428: E/DatabaseUtils(21572):     at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:652)
07-31 11:41:57.428: E/DatabaseUtils(21572):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:189)
07-31 11:41:57.428: E/DatabaseUtils(21572):     at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:113)
07-31 11:41:57.428: E/DatabaseUtils(21572):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:351)
07-31 11:41:57.428: E/DatabaseUtils(21572):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Code:

```
package com.piqsho.p.d.h;

import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.text.TextUtils;

public class CP extends ContentProvider {
    static final String PROVIDER_NAME = "com.piqsho.provider";
    public static final String U_URL = "content://" + PROVIDER_NAME + "/user";
    public static final Uri U_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(U_URL);

    public static final String C_URL = "content://" + PROVIDER_NAME + "/chat";
    public static final Uri C_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(C_URL);

    public static final String CF_URL = "content://" + PROVIDER_NAME
        + "/chat_file";
    public static final Uri CF_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(CF_URL);

    public static final String F_URL = "content://" + PROVIDER_NAME
        + "/friends";
    public static final Uri F_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(F_URL);

    public static final String PV_URL = "content://" + PROVIDER_NAME
        + "/phone_verification";
    public static final Uri PV_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(PV_URL);

    public static final String UP_URL = "content://" + PROVIDER_NAME
        + "/user_pictures";
    public static final Uri UP_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(UP_URL);

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "piqsho_android.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    // USER DETAILS
    public static final String TABLE_USER = "user";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID_USER = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_USER_ID = "user_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_FNAME = "fname";
    public static final String COLUMN_ONAMES = "onames";
    public static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String COLUMN_PHONE = "phone_no";
    public static final String COLUMN_LAST_LOGIN = "last_login";
    public static final String COLUMN_REGISTER_DATE = "reg_date";

    // Database creation sql statement for user
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_USER = "create table "
        + TABLE_USER + "(" + COLUMN_ID_USER
        + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_USER_ID
        + " integer not null, " + COLUMN_EMAIL + " text null, "
        + COLUMN_PHONE + " text null, " + COLUMN_FNAME + " text null, "
        + COLUMN_ONAMES + " text null," + COLUMN_LAST_LOGIN
        + " text not null, " + COLUMN_REGISTER_DATE + " text not null);";

    // C DETAILS
    public static final String TABLE_CHAT = "chat";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID_CHAT = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_CHAT_ID = "message_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_CHAT_TO = "toId";
    public static final String COLUMN_CHAT_FROM = "fromId";
    public static final String COLUMN_CHAT_MSG = "message";
    public static final String COLUMN_CHAT_SENTTIME = "senttime";
    public static final String COLUMN_CHAT_RECD = "recd";
    public static final String COLUMN_CHAT_IS_DELETED = "isDeleted";

    // Database creation sql statement for chat
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_CHAT = "create table "
        + TABLE_CHAT + "(" + COLUMN_ID_CHAT
        + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_CHAT_ID
        + " integer null, " + COLUMN_CHAT_TO + " integer not null, "
        + COLUMN_CHAT_FROM + " integer not null, " + COLUMN_CHAT_MSG
        + " text not null, " + COLUMN_CHAT_SENTTIME + " text not null,"
        + COLUMN_CHAT_RECD + " integer not null," + COLUMN_CHAT_IS_DELETED
        + " tinyint not null default '0');";

    // CF DETAILS
    public static final String TABLE_CHAT_FILE = "chat_file";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID_CHAT_FILE = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_CHAT_FILE_ID = "chat_file_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_CHAT_FILE_NAME = "file_name";
    public static final String COLUMN_CHAT_MSG_ID = "chat_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_CHAT_DATE_TIME = "date_time";
    public static final String COLUMN_CHAT_ID_LOCAL = "id_chat";
    public static final String COLUMN_CHAT_FILE_IS_DELETED = "isDeleted";

    // Database creation sql statement for chat
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_CHAT_FILE = "create table "
        + TABLE_CHAT_FILE + "(" + COLUMN_ID_CHAT_FILE
        + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_CHAT_FILE_ID
        + " integer null, " + COLUMN_CHAT_FILE_NAME + " text not null,"
        + COLUMN_CHAT_MSG_ID + " integer not null, "
        + COLUMN_CHAT_DATE_TIME + " text not null," + COLUMN_CHAT_ID_LOCAL
        + " text not null," + COLUMN_CHAT_FILE_IS_DELETED
        + " tinyint not null default '0');";

    // FRIENDS DETAILS
    public static final String TABLE_FRIENDS = "friends";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID_FRIENDS = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_FRIENDS_ID = "id_friends";
    public static final String COLUMN_F_USER_ID = "user_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_F_ID = "friend_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_F_FNAME = "fname";
    public static final String COLUMN_F_ONAMES = "onames";
    public static final String COLUMN_F_SEX = "sex";
    public static final String COLUMN_F_STATUS = "status";
    public static final String COLUMN_F_ISONLINE = "is_online";
    public static final String COLUMN_F_LAST_ONLINE = "last_online";
    public static final String COLUMN_F_DOB = "dob";
    public static final String COLUMN_F_OCCUPATION = "occupation";
    public static final String COLUMN_F_PROFILE_PIC_NAME = "profile_pic_name";
    public static final String COLUMN_F_PHONE_NO = "phone_no";

    // Database creation sql statement for friends
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_FRIEND = "create table "
        + TABLE_FRIENDS + "(" + COLUMN_ID_FRIENDS
        + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_FRIENDS_ID
        + " integer  null, " + COLUMN_F_USER_ID + " integer  null, "
        + COLUMN_F_ID + " integer  null, " + COLUMN_F_FNAME
        + " text  null, " + COLUMN_F_ONAMES + " text  null, "
        + COLUMN_F_SEX + " text  null," + COLUMN_F_STATUS + " text  null, "
        + COLUMN_F_ISONLINE + " text  null," + COLUMN_F_LAST_ONLINE
        + " text  null," + COLUMN_F_DOB + " text  null,"
        + COLUMN_F_OCCUPATION + " text  null," + COLUMN_F_PROFILE_PIC_NAME
        + " text  null," + COLUMN_F_PHONE_NO + " text  null);";

    // Network Operator DETAILS
    public static final String TABLE_PHONE_VERIFICATION = "phone_verification";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID_PV = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_V_CODE = "v_code";
    public static final String COLUMN_V_PNO = "phone_number";
    public static final String COLUMN_V_COUNTRY = "country";
    public static final String COLUMN_V_COUNTRY_CODE = "country_code";
    public static final String COLUMN_V_DATE = "date";
    public static final String COLUMN_V_STATUS = "status";

    // Database creation sql statement for Network Operator
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_PHONE_VERIFICATION = "create table "
        + TABLE_PHONE_VERIFICATION
        + "("
        + COLUMN_ID_PV
        + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + COLUMN_V_CODE
        + " text null, "
        + COLUMN_V_PNO
        + " text null, "
        + COLUMN_V_COUNTRY
        + " text null, "
        + COLUMN_V_COUNTRY_CODE
        + " text null, "
        + COLUMN_V_DATE
        + " text null, "
        + COLUMN_V_STATUS
        + " tinyint not null default '0');";

    public static final String TABLE_USER_PICS = "user_pictures";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID_USER_PICS = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_UP_USER_ID = "user_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_UP_URL = "url";
    public static final String COLUMN_UP_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_UP_TYPE = "type";
    public static final String COLUMN_UP_ACTIVE = "active";
    public static final String COLUMN_UP_IS_DELETED = "is_deleted";
    public static final String COLUMN_UP_DATE = "date";

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_USER_PICS = "create table "
        + TABLE_USER_PICS + "(" + COLUMN_ID_USER_PICS
        + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_UP_USER_ID
        + " text null, " + COLUMN_UP_URL + " text null, " + COLUMN_UP_NAME
        + " text null, " + COLUMN_UP_TYPE + " text null, "
        + COLUMN_UP_ACTIVE + " tinyint not null default '0',"
        + COLUMN_UP_IS_DELETED + " text null, " + COLUMN_UP_DATE
        + " text null);";

    static final int u = 1;
    static final int u_id = 2;

    static final int cds = 3;
    static final int cds_id = 4;

    static final int fds = 5;
    static final int fds_id = 6;

    static final int pv = 7;
    static final int pv_id = 8;

    static final int up = 9;
    static final int up_id = 10;

    static final int cfds = 11;
    static final int cfds_id = 12;

    // projection map for a query
    private static HashMap<String, String> UMap;
    private static HashMap<String, String> CDSMap;
    private static HashMap<String, String> FDSMap;
    private static HashMap<String, String> PVMap;
    private static HashMap<String, String> UPMap;
    private static HashMap<String, String> CFDSMap;

    static final UriMatcher uriMatcher;
    static {
    uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, TABLE_USER, u);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, TABLE_USER + "/#", u_id);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, TABLE_CHAT, cds);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, TABLE_CHAT + "/#", cds_id);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, TABLE_CHAT_FILE, cfds);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, TABLE_CHAT_FILE + "/#", cfds_id);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, TABLE_FRIENDS, fds);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, TABLE_FRIENDS + "/#", fds_id);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, TABLE_PHONE_VERIFICATION, pv);
    uriMatcher
    .addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, TABLE_PHONE_VERIFICATION + "/#", pv_id);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, TABLE_USER_PICS, up);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, TABLE_USER_PICS + "/#", up_id);
    }

    private DBH dbHelper;

    private static class DBH extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    DBH(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_USER);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_CHAT);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_CHAT_FILE);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_FRIEND);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_PHONE_VERIFICATION);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_USER_PICS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CHAT);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CHAT_FILE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_FRIENDS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PHONE_VERIFICATION);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER_PICS);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    int count = 0;
    String id = uri.getLastPathSegment(); // gets the id
    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
    case u:
        // delete all the records of the table
        count = db.delete(TABLE_USER, selection, selectionArgs);
        break;
    case u_id:

        count = db.delete(TABLE_USER, COLUMN_ID_USER
            + " = "
            + id
            + (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? " AND (" + selection
                + ')' : ""), selectionArgs);
        break;
    case cds:
        // delete all the records of the table
        count = db.delete(TABLE_CHAT, selection, selectionArgs);
        break;
    case cds_id:
        count = db.delete(TABLE_CHAT, COLUMN_ID_CHAT
            + " = "
            + id
            + (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? " AND (" + selection
                + ')' : ""), selectionArgs);
        break;
    case cfds:
        // delete all the records of the table
        count = db.delete(TABLE_CHAT_FILE, selection, selectionArgs);
        break;
    case cfds_id:
        count = db.delete(TABLE_CHAT_FILE, COLUMN_ID_CHAT_FILE
            + " = "
            + id
            + (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? " AND (" + selection
                + ')' : ""), selectionArgs);
        break;
    case fds:
        // delete all the records of the table
        count = db.delete(TABLE_FRIENDS, selection, selectionArgs);
        break;
    case fds_id:
        count = db.delete(TABLE_FRIENDS, COLUMN_ID_FRIENDS
            + " = "
            + id
            + (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? " AND (" + selection
                + ')' : ""), selectionArgs);
        break;
    case pv:
        // delete all the records of the table
        count = db.delete(TABLE_PHONE_VERIFICATION, selection,
            selectionArgs);
        break;
    case pv_id:
        count = db.delete(TABLE_PHONE_VERIFICATION, COLUMN_ID_PV
            + " = "
            + id
            + (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? " AND (" + selection
                + ')' : ""), selectionArgs);
        break;
    case up:
        // delete all the records of the table
        count = db.delete(TABLE_USER_PICS, selection, selectionArgs);
        break;
    case up_id:
        count = db.delete(TABLE_USER_PICS, COLUMN_ID_USER_PICS
            + " = "
            + id
            + (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? " AND (" + selection
                + ')' : ""), selectionArgs);
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI " + uri);
    }

    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return count;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
    // Get all user records
    case u:
        return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.android.provider.cp.user";
        // Get a user
    case u_id:
        return "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.android.provider.cp.user";
    case cds:
        return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.android.provider.cp.chat";
        // Get a chat
    case cds_id:
        return "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.android.provider.cp.chat";
    case cfds:
        return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.android.provider.cp.chat";
        // Get a chat file
    case cfds_id:
        return "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.android.provider.cp.chat";
    case fds:
        return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.android.provider.cp.friends";
        // Get a particular friend
    case fds_id:
        return "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.android.provider.cp.friends";
    case pv:
        return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.android.provider.cp.phone_verification";
        // Get a particular picture
    case pv_id:
        return "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.android.provider.cp.phone_verification";
    case up:
        return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.android.provider.cp.user_pictures";
        // Get a particular user profile
    case up_id:
        return "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.android.provider.cp.user_pictures";
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI: " + uri);
    }
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    Uri _uri = null;
    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
    case u:
        long row1 = db.insert(TABLE_USER, "", values);

        if (row1 > 0) {
        Uri newUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(U_CONTENT_URI, row1);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(newUri, null);
        return newUri;
        }
        break;
    case cds:
        long rowc = db.insert(TABLE_CHAT, "", values);

        if (rowc > 0) {
        Uri newUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(C_CONTENT_URI, rowc);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(newUri, null);
        return newUri;
        }
        break;
    case cfds:
        long rowcf = db.insert(TABLE_CHAT_FILE, "", values);

        if (rowcf > 0) {
        Uri newUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CF_CONTENT_URI, rowcf);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(newUri, null);
        return newUri;
        }
        break;
    case fds:
        long rowf = db.insert(TABLE_FRIENDS, "", values);

        if (rowf > 0) {
        Uri newUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(F_CONTENT_URI, rowf);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(newUri, null);
        return newUri;
        }
        break;
    case pv:
        long rowpv = db.insert(TABLE_PHONE_VERIFICATION, "", values);

        if (rowpv > 0) {
        Uri newUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(PV_CONTENT_URI, rowpv);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(newUri, null);
        return newUri;
        }
        break;
    case up:
        long rowup = db.insert(TABLE_USER_PICS, "", values);

        if (rowup > 0) {
        Uri newUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(UP_CONTENT_URI, rowup);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(newUri, null);
        return newUri;
        }
        break;
    default:
        throw new SQLException("Fail to add a new record into " + uri);
    }
    return _uri;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
    Context context = getContext();
    dbHelper = new DBH(context);
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    if (db == null)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    qb.setTables(TABLE_USER);

    SQLiteQueryBuilder cqb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    cqb.setTables(TABLE_CHAT);

    SQLiteQueryBuilder cfqb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    cfqb.setTables(TABLE_CHAT_FILE);

    SQLiteQueryBuilder fqb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    fqb.setTables(TABLE_FRIENDS);

    SQLiteQueryBuilder pvqb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    pvqb.setTables(TABLE_PHONE_VERIFICATION);

    SQLiteQueryBuilder upqb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    upqb.setTables(TABLE_USER_PICS);

    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
    case u:
        qb.setProjectionMap(UMap);
        break;
    case u_id:
        qb.appendWhere(COLUMN_ID_USER + "=" + uri.getLastPathSegment());
        break;
    case cds:
        cqb.setProjectionMap(CDSMap);
        break;
    case cds_id:
        cqb.appendWhere(COLUMN_ID_CHAT + "=" + uri.getLastPathSegment());
        break;
    case cfds:
        cqb.setProjectionMap(CFDSMap);
        break;
    case cfds_id:
        cqb.appendWhere(COLUMN_ID_CHAT_FILE + "="
            + uri.getLastPathSegment());
        break;
    case fds:
        fqb.setProjectionMap(FDSMap);
        break;
    case fds_id:
        fqb.appendWhere(COLUMN_ID_FRIENDS + "=" + uri.getLastPathSegment());
        break;
    case pv:
        pvqb.setProjectionMap(PVMap);
        break;
    case pv_id:
        pvqb.appendWhere(COLUMN_ID_PV + "=" + uri.getLastPathSegment());
        break;
    case up:
        upqb.setProjectionMap(UPMap);
        break;
    case up_id:
        upqb.appendWhere(COLUMN_ID_USER_PICS + "="
            + uri.getLastPathSegment());
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
    }

    SQLiteQueryBuilder finalQb = null;

    if (uriMatcher.match(uri) == u || uriMatcher.match(uri) == u_id) {
        finalQb = qb;
    }

    if (uriMatcher.match(uri) == cds || uriMatcher.match(uri) == cds_id) {
        finalQb = cqb;
    }

    if (uriMatcher.match(uri) == cfds || uriMatcher.match(uri) == cfds_id) {
        finalQb = cfqb;
    }

    if (uriMatcher.match(uri) == fds || uriMatcher.match(uri) == fds_id) {
        finalQb = fqb;
    }
    if (uriMatcher.match(uri) == pv || uriMatcher.match(uri) == pv_id) {
        finalQb = pvqb;
    }
    if (uriMatcher.match(uri) == up || uriMatcher.match(uri) == up_id) {
        finalQb = upqb;
    }
    /*
     * cursor
     */
    Cursor c = finalQb.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null,
        null, sortOrder);

    /**
     * register to watch a content URI for changes
     */
    try {
        if(c != null && c.getCount() > 0){
        c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        if(c != null){
        c.close();
        }
    }

    return c;
    }
```

Where could the problem be?

Comment: @musefan i have come to terms with my failure and that is y i have posted code so you could help point out what i can since i have failed

Comment: Sorry, I was confused by the bit where you said "i have written code correctly"

Comment: There's probably 500 lines of code to wade through here, and thus it is likely too broad as a Stack Overflow question. Can you create a demonstration app containing 50 lines of code that crashes in the same way? Narrowing the problem down for readers may help you identify the problem yourself.

Comment: From the guidelines: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary** to reproduce it in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

In your table user,
You have specified "COLUMN_USER_ID"

```
COLUMN_USER_ID+ " integer not null,
```

And while inserting data in user table, COLUMN_USER_ID is somehow null.
So creating issue.
Make sure that column value is not null before inserting data.

Comment: I have changed that but it does not solve the problem, i still get the errors

Comment: Checkout same minor mistakes in all your queries of inserting data

Comment: which mistakes do u mean